# Short circuit connection between client and aiohttp web server

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing an application that use aiohttp to publish a web api. I also need to publish the same api with another protocol (xmpp). Currently the solution is to embed an xmpp client in the same process that connects to the web api using a regular HTTP connection (aiohttp client) and forwards the response through xmpp. But since they are both running in the same process I would prefer if there was a way to "short circuit" the connection.

I'm thinking something like creating a Request instance and passing it to a method in the aiohttp web application (perhaps the `_handle()` method?) to process it.

Any hints on how to do this in a (preferably) non-hackish manner?

Answer (score 0):

I have something working now that at least does not depend on private methods:

```
req = Request(...)
req.match_info = await app.router.resolve("/api/1.0/status")
response = req.match_info.handler(req)
```

This works, but there's room for improvements. I use a custom, simplified Request class as well:

```
from yarl import URL

class XmppHttpRequest:
    def __init__(self, method, path):
        self.method = method
        self.path = path
        self.rel_url = URL(path)
        self.url = self.rel_url
        self.match_info = None
```

This is all I require for now.